# indefinite article for generic reference

Tags: articles, indefinite-article, generic-noun-phrases

I understand that an indefinite article + noun can refer to the whole class, but also refer to one of them. which of the following sentences are generic reference? Thank you.

1. A horse is a useful animal.
2. I don't have a question.
3. I like watching a movie.
4. would you like a sandwich?

Answer (score 1):

1. 

- "A horse" means "one non-specific horse".
- The next "a" is used because "we classify or define people and things - when we say what they are, what job they do, or what they are used for."

2. 

- "one non-specific question"
- It sounds unnatural to me. I would say: I don't have any questions (but this sentence means something different)

3. 

- "one non specific movie".
- Note that you don't say that you like watching movies in general.
- For example A: What do like doing after work? B: I like watching a movie. (=one non-specific movie)

4. 

- "one non-specific sandwich"

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But in my opinion, the 1st sentence, would a horse refer to any horse? For the 2nd, if I say I don't have a car, does it still sound unnatural?  Also, what's the differences between singular (a car) and plural(cars) in negative statements?

Comment: 1. See 3 https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html

Comment: 2. 'I don't have a car' sounds natural to me

Comment: 3. 'I don't have cars' - I don't have two or more cars but perhaps I have one car. 'I don't have a car' - I have zero cars.